# Angular2 - redirect after login

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to navigate my user on another route after login.

I found out in documentation that something like this should work for it correctly:

```
this.router.navigate(['/users']);
```

My full method in compoenent looks like:

```
// imports on top
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

// method somewhere below
login(event, username, password) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let body = JSON.stringify({ username, password });

  this.loginService.login(body)
      .then(res => localStorage.setItem('token', res.msg))
      .catch(error => this.error = error);

  this.router.navigate(['/users']);
}
```

However it doesn't redirect me. Basically route stays without change and no error spotted in console.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: 
My routes looks like:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  // users route protected by auth guard
  { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  // { path: 'user/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'users' }

];
```

My AuthGuard looks like:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      // logged in so return true
      return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: what data are you getting in response from loginService.login , if it is false the AuthGuard prevents user from accessing that route

Comment: Hey @AnmolMittal it is JSON object :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem on my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270309/angular-2-0-router-navigate-not-redirecting-after-login/40292872#40292872). The problem is that there is a delay in authenticating your user but `router.navigate` executes instantly. As the users part of your site is protected and your technically still unauthenticated, it fails the redirect.

By redirecting on the `.then` it waits for your user to login, and then if successful it redirects your user.

Try using this:

```
this.loginService.login(body)
      .then(
            res => localStorage.setItem('token', res.msg)
            this.router.navigate(['/users']);
       )
      .catch(error => this.error = error);
```

Answer (score 0):

this.router.navigate(['/users']);
This should be called after localStorage.setItem(), inside the .then() function

If it still doesn't work, may you put the code of the class in your message please

Comment: Hey @Alexis Le Gall, thank you for your answer. I agree that to make it correct it should be inside of `.then`. However this should not affect if route change or not. This should just make change if it redirect before or after that `response` from service comes

Comment: The error may come from your routing file, hard to say with just this part of the code

Comment: Edited my question and added requested files :)

Comment: The AuthGuard prevent the route to be activated until the user is connected