# Angular 2.0 Router.navigate not redirecting after login

Tags: redirect, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have a simple application connected up to firebase. On login, I simply want to redirect the user to their profile page. However, for some odd reason the redirect is not happening.

I have look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226651/angular2-redirect-after-login) which sounds like a similar problem, but unfortunately, no solution there.

Changing the redirect to another page (one which does not have an auth guard) seems to work, so I guess the problem is there, I just don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code, once the user signs in it calls my service:

```
onLogin() {
    this.authService.signinUser(this.loginForm.value);
 }
```

And my `auth.service.ts`:

```
public signinUser(user: User) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .catch(function (error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            let errorCode = error.code;
            let errorMessage = error.message;
            // todo
            console.log(errorCode);
            console.log(errorMessage);
        });

        this.router.navigate(['/profile']); //not working
        //this.router.navigate(['/']); //working
    }
```

Here is my `app.routing.ts`

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

And here is my `auth.guard.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        return this.authService.isAuthenticated().first();
    }
}
```

The full project is on [github](https://github.com/gudthing/SiteDrop), incase you need to check another configuration.

Comment: do you get any error on the console?

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray absolutely nothing, console is all clean. The only slightly weird thing is that if I re-click 'sign in' button, it does redirect but only on second attempt

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray What does this return when you are logged in?
`canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        return this.authService.isAuthenticated().first();
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out! I was close, but as Jan pointed in his answer, the navigation happened immediaately, before the signup and authentication was established. By tapping into `.then` I was able to perform the operation once the user had been created.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then(success => {
            this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `auth` or `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method probably returns `Observable` so they are delayed. Router navigation happens immediately. Try to include it into `subscribe()` call.